# Chrome v113 Regex not accepting some special character in character classes

Tags: javascript, regex, google-chrome

The recent chrome v 133 not accepting some special character in character class, for example :

`^[\u4e00-\u9faf ,.'-]+$,`
it's not valid in chrome 113 and giving **`Pattern attribute value ^[\u4e00-\u9faf ,.'-]+$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[\u4e00-\u9faf ,.'-]+$/v: Invalid character in character class`** error, and must be like this in order to work :

`^[\u4e00-\u9faf ,.'\-]+$` => adding a backslash to "-".

But precedent versions and mozilla are working fine, and i didn't fine any documentaion for it, is this a bug for chrome and engine v8 in general ?.

trying `^[\u4e00-\u9faf ,.'-]+$` regular expresion, expecting to work as previous version of chrome.

Comment: HTML `<input>` patterns are now compiled with the recently-added `v` flag, which requires you to escape `-` inside character classes. See the comments at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76462550).